# XP machines on Domain not reporting WMI Data in a 2003 Server Environment

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, windows, wmi

I am running into a very quirky issue and I hope someone out there can help. We use a monitoring program for several networks we oversee that is WMI data dependent for a great deal of it's functionality. The Windows 2000 Professional workstations, as well as the 2003 servers in our network report WMI data fine, the Windows XP professional machines will not let me view them from within the WMI snap in for MMC (they return a Win32: Access Denied) error. I am of course logged in with an account with domain admin privileges on the domain controller when I attempt it. DCOM is enabled in component services, and the remote security option is set to allow as well. If we remove the machine from the domain and rejoin it, some workstations will show up as WMI enabled temporarily and then when I try to access them again later I get the access denied error again out of the blue. Hoping someone out there has had a similar problem or they have advice. I have had this problem with the firewall turned on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive troubleshooting, it turned out that the XP Machines needed to have "network service" added to local administrators group. As soon as we did that and pushed it out through a GPO calling on the "net" command, they came right up and started reporting!

Comment: yikes, that seems like quite the sketchy solution. I wouldn't want to add a service account to the administrators group.

Comment: Agreed. This was the official solution we got from our 279$ call to Microsoft :)